# How to pass multiple comma separated values in a cell to a custom function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

Suppose, there are values such as `1,A`, `2,B`, `3,D` in certain cells. My intention is to add `1,2,3` (LHS) separately and `A,B,D` (RHS) separately. To achieve that, I have written certain custom function in "App script":

`function GetNumber (number, alphabet) { return number; }`

Now, how can I pass `1,A` to the `GetNumber()` as 2 arguments so that, the logic works?
I tried SPLIT, but it doesn't work:
`=GetNumber(SPLIT(C1,","))  // C1 is a column cell`

Though I am using Google sheet, MS-Excel equivalent may also help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of your problem is that `SPLIT`, when used as an argument to a function, returns a string. Say your `C1` cell contains the text `1,C`. Your formula

```
=GetNumber(SPLIT(C1, ","))
```

is actually equivalent to

```
=GetNumber('1C');
```

If you are somewhat familiar with JavaScript, you could instead do the split operation within your function code:

```
function GetNumber(input) {
  const [number, alphabet] = input.split(",");
  return number;
}
```

You could then call your function with

```
=GetNumber(C1)
```

and it should return `1`.

**Explanation (with links to relevant JavaScript documentation):**

The [`input.split(",")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) splits the input argument at `,`, returning an array of the two parts: `["1", "C"]`.

`const [number, alphabet]` is a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), picking out the two parts of the array, storing them in separate variables.

This makes it possible for our function to return the desired variable: `return number`.